# WildFly messaging, deployment does not respect clustered configuration

Tags: messaging, wildfly, wildfly-8, hornetq

We ran into some kind of trouble configuring messaging on WildFly 8.2 (in domain mode). Somehow deployment does not take proper configuration (clustered=true, cluster password) and reverts to some default. Weird part that no configuration file (domain.xml on domain controller, host.xml on host controller) has the values of clustered=false and cluster-password="CHANGE ME!!!"
Here's output of CLI to give you an idea:

```
[domain@AAA:9990 /] /profile=Test/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default:read-attribute(name=clustered)  
{  
  "outcome" => "success",  
  "result" => true  
}  
[domain@AAA:9990 /] /host=BBB/server=CCC-test/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default:read-attribute(name=clustered)  
{  
  "outcome" => "success",  
  "result" => true  
}  
[domain@AAA:9990 /] /host=BBB/server=CCC-test/deployment=DDD.war/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default:read-attribute  
(name=clustered)  
{  
  "outcome" => "success",  
  "result" => false  
}
```

Is there any way to debug it to see where exactly are configuration values coming from?

Comment: You can try set TRACE level for org.jboss.as.config (or even for org.jboss) and grep log.

Comment: Tried with both, there's no mention of any configuration values.

Comment: I think it will be necessary to see your domain.xml to help you.